# Assign base object of child object

Tags: c#, inheritance

I have a base class and a child class. Base class contains some variables and child contains some variables.

What I need to do is that when I create object of child class, I pass base class object in its constructor which will set base class variables of child object.

Code:

```
public class BaseClass
{
    public int BaseInteger;
    public double BaseDouble;
    public bool BaseBool;
}

public class ChildClass : BaseClass
{
    public ChildClass(BaseClass baseClass)
    {
        this.base = baseClass;     // I am trying to do this.
    }

    public int ChildInteger;
    public string ChildString;
}
```

So is it possible what I am trying to do here. How? When I tried this code I got this error.

```
Use of keyword 'base' is not valid in this context
```

Answer (score 5):

You have to realize that `ChildClass` does not **contain** `BaseClass` but rather **inherits** from it.

That is why you can access data and methods that were defined in the base class using the `this` keyword (`this.BaseInteger` for example).

And that is also why you cannot 'set' the `BaseClass` of your `ChildClass`, it doesn't contain one.

Nevertheless, there are some useful patterns to achieve what you're trying to do, for example:

```
public class BaseClass
{
    protected BaseClass() {}

    protected BaseClass(BaseClass initData)
    {
        this.BaseInteger = initData.BaseInteger;
        this.BaseDouble = initData.BaseDouble;
        this.BaseBool = initData.BaseBool;
    }

    public int BaseInteger;
    public double BaseDouble;
    public bool BaseBool;
}

public class ChildClass : BaseClass
{
    public ChildClass() {}

    public ChildClass(BaseClass baseClass) : base(baseClass)
    {
    }

    public int ChildInteger;
    public string ChildString;
}
```

Thanks to @svick for his suggestions.

Comment: you have mistakenly used `class` keyword with base class constructor

Comment: I would consider making the `BaseClass` constructor `protected`, if it's supposed to be used only from child classes. Also, `BaseClass` needs another constructor, so that you can create an instance withou copying it from another one.

Comment: @svick, true. i was just too lazy to add it. revised.

Comment: The problem what I see in this is what if there are too many variables in base class, and what if base class is derived from another class and contains some complex class objects in it. Then the protected constructor would be very large enough.

Comment: I meant that `BaseClass` needs another constructor, not `ChildClass`. Your current code wouldn't even compile.

Comment: Added the parameterless ctor.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class BaseClass
{
    public int BaseInteger;
    public double BaseDouble;
    public bool BaseBool;
}

public class ChildClass : BaseClass
{
    public ChildClass(BaseClass baseClass)
    {
        this.BaseInteger = baseClass.BaseInteger;
        this.BaseDouble = baseClass.BaseDouble;
        this.BaseBool = baseClass.BaseBool;
    }

    public int ChildInteger;
    public string ChildString;
}
```

Comment: You can also put that constructor in `BaseClass` itself and then just pass the reference up

Answer (score 1):

I think the most elegant way is to create a second constructor in the `BaseClass` class that takes a `BaseClass` instance from which it should initialize its fields. Then you can simply call this base constructor in your `ChildClass` class:

```
public class BaseClass
{
    public int BaseInteger;
    public double BaseDouble;
    public bool BaseBool;

    public BaseClass()
    {
    }

    public BaseClass(BaseClass baseClass)
    {
        this.BaseInteger = baseClass.BaseInteger;
        this.BaseDouble = baseClass.BaseDouble;
        this.BaseBool = baseClass.BaseBool;
    }
}

public class ChildClass : BaseClass
{
    public int ChildInteger;
    public string ChildString;

    public ChildClass(BaseClass baseClass) : base(baseClass)
    {
    }
```

}

Comment: The problem what I see in this is what if there are too many variables in base class, and what if base class is derived from another class and contains some complex class objects in it. Then the protected constructor would be very large enough.